# ASCII Art Generator

Tags: ascii-art, code-challenge

Your goal is to write a program / script which "converts" real images into ascii art.

**General:**
Your program will get a path to a image file over stdin or as parameter (whatever you prefer). The format will be jpeg.
It should "convert" it to ascii art and save it to the harddrive.
The image will be in grayscale. You don't have to check if the input file exists or the file is a valid image.
You can use any utf-8 character in your outputfile.

**Rules:**

- You must be able to recognize the output image.
- Your program must recognize the path on `stdin` or parameters
- The content of the original image must be read from the drive (you get only the path
  to the file)
- No user interaction (except giving the parameters at startup) allowed
- Must terminate without any error message
- The output must be written to the harddrive (output  name is up to you)
- Only turing complete languages allowed.
- If you require any special language version for your program you have to add it to your answer. Otherwise the newest stable version will be used (e.g. python = python 3.3)

**Bonus points:**

- -10 Points for every additional image format your program can convert (please write down which formats can be recognized)
- -25 Points if your program can change the output size (width / height parameters at startup in characters)
- -100 Points if you don't use any Image Processing libraries (e.g. PIL, ImageMagic, GD...)
- -50 Points if your program source looks like ascii art itself ;)

**Formula to calculate your points:**

`points = floor(programSize (in Bytes) * avgRuntimeOnTestInput (in seconds) - BonusPoints)`

**How your program will be tested:**
All programs will run on a new virtual machine running Debian x64 (current version) with 512MB memory, 2x3,4Ghz CPU.
The time will be calculated on an average of three pictures per format with different size and content (every program will be use the same files).
Please write your programcall into your answer so i can check it (and if required the needed compile parameters).
Example program call (with bonus parameters):
`python ascii.py -file /home/chill0r/test/MyPicture.jpeg -width 1000 -height 750 -out /home/chill0r/test/MyPictureAscii.txt`
I'll check the answers every few days and post a 'low score' (*high score* doesn't really fit on code golf...). (Meaning you don't have to calculate your points on your own)

Comment: First, I've only been here for a week and already seen multiple ASCII challenges. This one is even more general than the last two. Second, if I have the fastest code, and someone else has the shortest code, who wins? I suggest removing the "fastest-code" tag or the "code-golf" tag - probably remove the former judging by your scoring system. Then, put a spin on your question that makes it unique from other ASCII challenges.

Comment: I have removed [tag:fastest-code] since it is obvious from the question that this is a code-golf challenge.

Comment: "You must be able to recognize the output image." - isn't this too subjective? I thought to post this question too but couldn't come up with a way to enforce this objectively.

Comment: One objective approach to "able to recognize" I have been able to think of is for poster to hire people on something like Mechanical Turk to see if they recognize the image. But that creates a problem if poster wanders off distracted by something shiny and new answers are still coming in. So I thought of one better: poster writes a test harness that rasterizes the ASCII images and algorithmically evaluates them for similarity to the original image, and posts the source for the tester in the question. Then at least you have a verifiable authority.

Comment: Bonus points are listed with negative values, but they are subtracted in the score formula, that makes them to penalties?

Comment: changed tag to code-challenge since the scoring depends on both code size and runtime

Comment: I don't think a comparison of execution times is particularly worthwhile. The amount of computation involved in unpacking a JPEG image is far, far greater than the computation needed to convert the image into ASCII art. I also don't really like the idea of having to write software to run on a computer system that I have no access to. I really wish you'd discussed this question in the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/proposed-questions-sandbox-mark-x) before posting it here.

Comment: @squeamish ossifrage In fact there already exists [a question](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1250/12205) in the sandbox that is very similar to, but better-written than, this. I want to close this as duplicate, but technically the one in the sandbox isn't posted...

Comment: @GrantMiller I appreciate that you're aiming to improve the site via your edits, but it is usually recommended to only edit around 5 posts in a short period of time, as to not flood the home page with questions from 2014. Please continue editing, but also refrain from making mass edits in a short amount of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Mathematica

`asciiPhoto[image_,rastersize_:125,shades_:3]` scans the image according to the raster size (default=125), quantizes it into up to 7 shades (3 by default), then replaces the shading with ASCII characters of varying darkness.   Hints about relative darkness found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23362/sort-characters-by-darkness/23375#23375).  The characters are stored in `shades`; for some reason, 2 of them disappeared in the cut and paste to SE.

```
asciiPhoto[image_,rastersize_:125,shades_:3]:=
Module[{chars,gray},
chars={{},{"M"," "},{"","/"," "},{"P","o","/"," "},{"W","o","/",""," "},
{"","b","o","/",""," "},{"","M","b","o","/",""," "},};
gray=ImageData[ColorQuantize[Rasterize[image,RasterSize->rastersize+1,
ImageSize->rastersize],shades]];
GraphicsGrid[gray/.Thread[Union@Flatten[gray,1]->chars[[shades]]],ImageSize->500]]
```

### Examples

Render the merganser with a raster size of 35 in 4 shades; compare it to a raster size of 85 with 5 shades.

[image: merganzer]

```
{asciiPhoto[merganzer, 35, 4], asciiPhoto[merganzer, 85, 5]}
```

---

[image: merg2]

---

Raster size of 125 in 2 shades; same raster size with 7 shades.

```
{asciiPhoto[merganzer, 125, 2], asciiPhoto[merganzer, 125, 7]}
```

[image: merganzer3]

---

Let's not forget Greta.

[image: greata]

Comment: **Very** nice. The only observation isn't programming related: Let Greta go. :)

Comment: @belisarius, It seems I just can't get Greta out of my mind.

Comment: Well, it's a [shared weak point](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031725/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_2)

Comment: I invite you to spend a few pennies by downvotng [this one](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1078/315)

Comment: Happy to oblige.

Comment: I was just starting to golf this, but I doubt I could beat your solution. I leave my input here just in case you can use some ideas: `n = 128;
i = ColorConvert[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "Grayscale"];
n1 = ImageDimensions[i]/n;
ip = Rescale[
   Mean[Flatten[#]] & /@ (ImageData /@ 
      Flatten[ImagePartition[i, n1]])];
ch1 = CharacterRange["a", 
   FromCharacterCode[ToCharacterCode["a"] + 500]];
chars = Style[#, FontFamily -> "Monospaced"] & /@ ch1;`

Comment: `cc = Rescale[
   Mean[Flatten[#]] & /@ (ImageData /@ (ImagePad[#, {{1, 0}, {0, 
             0}} (16 - ImageDimensions@#), 
          White] & /@ (Rasterize[#, RasterSize -> 15] & /@ chars)))];
f = Nearest[cc];
ct = Thread[Rule[cc, ch1]];
p1 = Partition[f[#, 1][[1]] & /@ ip /. ct, n];
Rasterize[
 Style[StringJoin @@ (StringInsert[#, "\n", -1] & /@ (StringJoin @@@ 
       p1)), "Monospaced", LineSpacing -> {0, 8}]]`

Comment: Please remember it isn't golfed at all

Comment: The result is quite nice ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OPv8s.png)

Comment: @belisarius, Yes, the result is nice. I still need to explore the code to grasp its logic. BTW, this is a code-challenge question.

Comment: Yup. I realized the code-challenge tag too late :)

Comment: You call the first one a duck but it's easily recognizable as a specific type of duck, namely a male red-breasted merganser.  But there are some areas (like the side of the face) that are too light in the ASCII art.  I assume those were supposed to be in the two characters that you lost while pasting.

Comment: Yes. (about the real name).  I should have been more precise. I live on a lake that mergansers, tufted and common, visit at this time of the year.  You are also correct about the shading issues. I may look into that.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson, I fixed the label and tweaked the code so that all pixels are correctly rendered by shade.

Comment: Yes, definitely a red-breasted merganser now.  One upvote for you.